# How to explain to a young girl why I wear a headscarf?

Tags: practical-islam, hijab

Yesterday, I was asked by a young girl (who is maybe six or seven) why I wear a headscarf, and I didn't manage to come up with a reasonable explanation.

**Question**: How to explain to a young girl why I wear a headscarf?

"I'm Muslim and it says so in the Qur'an" doesn't feel like a particularly satisfying explanation to give a young girl; it seems too adult-level and complicated.  It also clashes a bit with some of my feminist beliefs (it sounds too much like "I do as I'm told", and I don't want to influence a young girl to think like that).  I'm still unsure what I should say at this point if she were to ask again.

Comment: ""I'm Muslim and it says so in the Qur'an" doesn't feel like a particularly satisfying explanation to give a young girl" "it sounds too much like "I do as I'm told", and I don't want to influence a young girl to think like that" - That is exactly why Muslimas wear hijab, other explanations would be pretenses and basically lies, no? If the texts commanding this didn't exist, we would most likely not see a significant proportion of Muslimas wear hijab - would you?

Comment: The question seems pretty subjective and is more likely to attract opinion-based answers.

Comment: just to be sure, you only want an answer specific for a young girl? Please clarify...if so what age are you talking about exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the girl's age and her background knowledge about religion ... she should be able to understand if you say "Because I am a Muslim and Muslims wear a headscarf, since God likes\ordains it".

You aren't living in a place where hijab is enforced legally; you do it of your own free choice because you want to be part of Islam and you want your attire to reflect your belonging.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to satisfy your child on the matter of hijab is that tell her it is told by ALLAH to cover ourselves and HE loves us and always wants the best for us.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this questions:

### Using your conscious

God loves me and I love God, he wants me to be modest for my own good*. He doesn't want me to show off my beauties to just everyone. I **want** to worship and make him happy. (The [more one is pious](https://quran.com/2/2-3) then more organic/easier the understanding of this happens)

### Using logic

With logical mindset we can at max prove that something is good, we can't never prove that it MUST be there. Or if we do the person may not understand the *must*. It has to come from the conscious.

- It makes a women more than beauty object.
- It protects a girl from having bad friends, her friends would no
  longer be friends who drink, have casual sex or do drugs. (Her hijab
  is acts like a big NO NO).
- It harnesses the lust for the husband only and only. Magnifying any experience between them.
- At the same time it helps other men to not think too much about women that don't belong to them. It just guides all casual, unsafe lust to a clean, organized relationship. I mean imagine if men and women were to just sleep together as they are now on Tinder and its likes. Hijab is a big no no to that, instead it says, let us just get married—if needed. If not then keep that desire for another lady to marry.

---

*: this is key, we don't do ahkam/commandments just because Allah *wants* us to, we do it's also for our own (and the society's) good

Comment: To me the answer is a complete mixture of them both

Comment: This answer is mostly apologetics and rationalizations with some slutshaming and other insults to Non-Muslims mixed in. It doesn't address that commandments are followed because they are in the texts, whether or not you can discern any benefit in them.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that I realize about this subject is this:
You should show her the real Islam. I mean the religion that Muslim people knows.

Not what is written in books or peoples head. In these days with ISIS's actions and people frightened when see a woman or a man with Islamic traditional clothes in streets.

You should show her who is our God. Most Gracious and Most Merciful are the words that we say after saying his name. You should show her that merciful and gracious God likes to see his servants happy and together. Sometimes in my life, I see headscarf are really helped women to live. So every time that someone asked me why women should put on a headscarf, I said him/her because your God want to see you like that.

But never force a girl to put on a headscarf. That is the worst way that we can do. By doing this we made her hate Islam.

Answer (score -2):

I would use something a 6 year old would understand. I would say "because I have many friends who do and I want to do like them". There is  (arguably ) some truth to it too. And this is something she will surely understand  (Kids this age like to dress up and usually pick someone they know or a fictional character as a model).

I would avoid speaking about god to a 6 year old, especially if I add orders from god. But that is for you to judge  (and the Kids parents).